# Recommendation for a Web 2.0-style site for managing membership for a non-profit?

Tags: webapp-rec

I volunteer with a non-profit that currently keeps their membership in a flaky Microsoft Access database. They've asked me for a recommendation on another solution. The requirements:

- manage list of members and keep track of who has paid their membership fees and when their membership expires
- print active membership lists
- print mailing labels
- allow people to self-register (desirable, not required)
- allow people to pay membership dues online (desirable, not required)

So far in my googling I have come across [Wild Apricot](http://www.wildapricot.com/), [Membee](http://www.membee.com/), [Memberize](http://www.memberize.com/), and [Club Express](http://clubexpress.com/).

Can anyone provide any recommendation from the above list based on my requirements, or a suggestion for another site?

Comment: You might want to try [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HHere's something that I think is perfect for what you are looking for:

http://civicrm.org/civimember

It's open source solution for civic organizations, non-profits, etc.  That means its free and can be customized to meet your specific needs if you employ a programmer.  Professional help can be found on the professional help tab on top.

There's also zoho creator.  Not as good, but is considered a simpler web 2.0 alternative to access.  Found an app in the marketplace in zoho that is membership related but pales in comparison to civicCRM in my opinion: search marketplace for membership.

There's also:  memplushome - search for that in google. but its expensive at least $400.

Good luck!

Comment: Great thank you, looks promising!

Answer (score 0):

Dolibarr might be used even though it is not targeting non-profits exclusively:
http://www.dolibarr.org

Answer (score 0):

The most popular in France is probably [Galette](http://galette.tuxfamily.org/fr/doku.php?id=apropos).

There seems to be an English version.